# pandas dataframe recognize column as date with a specific format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I would like to compute the maximum of each year in a dataframe where the first column is the date. The dataframe looks like:

```
date         ,A  obs ,A  sim ,B  obs ,C  sim 
1989-01-01:00,          46.920,           4.730,          59.300,           2.638
1989-01-01:01,          46.920,         167.329,          59.300,         373.360
1989-01-01:02,          46.920,         166.674,          59.300,         371.657
1989-01-01:03,          46.920,         166.024,          59.300,         369.970
1989-01-01:04,          46.920,         165.380,          59.300,         368.299
```

The firt step is of course read properly the dataframe. As a consequence, I did the following:

```
df  = pd.read_csv(fname ,sep=',',index_col=0,header=0,parse_dates=True)
```

However, if I try to test if the first column is recognize as data index I do the following:

```
df =    df.resample('M').sum()
```

I get the following error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/resample.py", line 1276, in _get_resampler
    "but got an instance of %r" % type(ax).__name__)

TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'
```

I do not understand why. Indeed, I have put parse_dates=True

Could you please help me? I have the filling that is something related to the format but I am not able to figure it out despite many searches.

Thanks

Comment: Check `df.index` and make sure you see dates. If not set the index to the date column like so `df = df.set_index('date')`

Comment: **Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].**

Comment: Your date is in a non-standard format so it tries to parse, can't, and keeps it as a string. You should use `pd.to_datetime` specifying the `format` after reading the data into a DataFrame. This is [spelt out explicitly in the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html): "For non-standard datetime parsing, use pd.to_datetime after pd.read_csv. "

Comment: Thanks. I have chanced the date format. I have just remove ":" and add a space. In this way the input file results more readable. It works, I will move to the second problem. Thanks